# Picasso, хранение картинок в кэше

Tags: java, android, adapter, picasso

Я хочу сохранить изображение в кэше, я использую libruary Пикассо. Ниже мой код. Я не могу понять как сохранить изображение в кэш с помощью адаптеров. Мой Алгоритм: если пользователь имеет доступ в Интернет -> я загрузить AsynkTask, если пользователь не интернет то загрузить список. Пожалуйста, помогите я много времени пробовал решить эту проблему

Main

```
//this i load json
ArrayList<NewsObject> newsList; 
ListView list; 

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    //code
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list); 
    newsList = new ArrayList<NewsObject>(); 
    //code 
//if i online then work  AsynkTask
    if(isOnline()) {
            new NewsAsynkTask().execute();
        } else {
            NewsAdapter adapter = new NewsAdapter(getApplicationContext(),   R.layout.n_news_list_object);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        } 
} 

public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && 
           cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }

public class NewsAsynkTask extends AsyncTask<String , Void, String> {         
    //code 
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) { 
        //this i add json to object,  
        //then i add in list object 
        newsList.add(newsObject); 
    } 

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) { 
        //adapter in game
        NewsAdapter adapter = new NewsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.n_news_list_object, newsList); 
        list.setAdapter(adapter); 
    } 
}
```

Adapter

```
public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewsObject>{

    ArrayList<NewsObject> ArrayListNews;
    int Resourse;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater vi;

    public NewsAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<NewsObject>objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        ArrayListNews = objects;
        Resourse = resource;
        this.context = context;

        vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public NewsAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);

        Resourse = resource;
        this.context = context;

        vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = vi.inflate(Resourse, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageNews);
            holder.nameNews = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameNews);
            holder.dayNews = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayNews);
            holder.monthNews = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.monthNews);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(ArrayListNews.get(position).getImage());
        Picasso.with(context).load(ArrayListNews.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.imageview);
        Picasso.with(context).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
        Picasso.with(context).setLoggingEnabled(true);

        holder.nameNews.setText(ArrayListNews.get(position).getNameNews());
        holder.dayNews.setText(ArrayListNews.get(position).getDayNews());
        holder.monthNews.setText(ArrayListNews.get(position).getMonthNews());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageview;
        public TextView nameNews;
        public TextView dayNews;
        public TextView monthNews;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Picasso сама загружает , кэширует картинки и работает с асинхронным потоком , вам не нужно делать ничего , кроме как сообщать Picasso url картинки , которая вам нужна . Библиотека сама сделает все остальное - загрузит в фоне или предоставит кэшированное изображение , если данный url ранее загружался . В адаптере вы указываете только адрес картинки и куда ее поместить :

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://imagehost.com/image.png").into(holder.imageview);
```

Если вам нужно каждый раз загружать обновленные изображения (то есть этот image.png на сервере постоянно меняется ) , а старое только при отсутствии интернета , то это решается с другой стороны . Picasso не в состоянии определить есть интернет или нет и соответственно предоставить либо файл из интернета либо из кэша .
Для такого нужна другая библиотека , picasso только кэширует статичные изображения (которые не должны изменяться со временем ) , чтобы не загружать каждый раз одно и то же , плюс еще некоторые трансформации изображений.

Comment: а какую библиотеку посоветуете для сохранение картинок в кэше(желательно jar)?